# MySQL Joins: Condition in subquery or ON?

Tags: mysql

Which is more efficient?

```
LEFT JOIN  cscart_seo_names seo
ON p.product_id = seo.object_id AND seo.type = 'p'
```

OR

```
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT seo.object_id, seo.name
            FROM cscart_seo_names seo
            WHERE seo.type = 'p'
        ) seo
            ON p.product_id = seo.object_id
```

Comment: The first, since indexes can be used to perform the join.

Comment: Please see yourself and share us the findings :)

Comment: @PraveenPrasannan This is a small part of a huge query that I am having a problem with. It's locking up the database and I am getting 504 time-outs. Not sure if I should be breaking up the query into smaller parts to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

The only reliable way to check efficiency is to check actual execution plan. Note, execution order is different from the order tables appear in the query.

In this particular case (assuming it's not a part of bigger query) , I'm pretty sure the optimizer will choose the same plan for both versions of your query...

Answer (score 0):

JOINs can create an execution plan that is better for your query and can predict what data should be loaded to be processed and save time, unlike the sub-query where it will run all the queries and load all their data to do the processing.

The good thing in sub queries is that they are more readable than JOINs: that's why most new SQL people prefer them; it is the easy way; but when it comes to performance, JOINS are better in most cases even though they are not hard to read too.